# Browser extension to temporarily hide incoming e-mails in the Gmail interface

Tags: chrome, gmail

It's not possible to temporarily hide incoming e-mails in the Gmail interface. I'm looking for a browser extension that can:

- temporarily hide incoming e-mails in the Gmail interface (e.g. by clicking a button "Hide incoming e-mails")

and if possible:

- free
- works with Google Chrome (and Windows 7 if OS-dependent)
- doesn't slow down the Gmail interface

E.g.

[image]

should be displayed as non-bold text without any (number_of_new_messages).

Answer (score 2):

I use [Minimalist for Everything](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/minimalist-for-everything/bmihblnpomgpjkfddepdpdafhhepdbek).
It is **free**, does work with **chrome**, and I **didn't notice any slowdown** in the Gmail interface.

The app can be activated and desactivated, which would act the same way as a "hide incoming emails" button. There is no setting by default to hide Inbox count or to unbold the thing, but you could hide the whole sidebar, the spam-count, or set up an item in the extension in order to modify just what you want to modify.

Comment: Thanks, great extension! Which option do you use to hide the whole sidebar? I've been looking for it but didn't find it.

Comment: Sorry @Frank, none actually. I thought there was one, as I hide the header myself. If you're fine with a bit of coding, you can set up a piece of css to do the trick for you(->Edit ->Add option).

Comment: No worry, still a great extension and should be easy to hide the inbox count indeed.